# Ansible Script dpkg lock on aws launch ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

I have a launch script (user data) that runs on startup in aws with an ubuntu 16.04 image, and the issue I'm having is that when it gets to the part where it runs an ansible playbook the playbook fails saying this basic error message `Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock`. Now when I log in and try to run the ansible script manually it works, but if I run it from the aws user data, it fails with the error.

This is the full error

```
TASK [rabbitmq : install packages (Ubuntu default repo is used)] ***************
task path: /etc/ansible/roles/rabbitmq/tasks/main.yml:50
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /tmp/tmpGHaVRP TO /.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586/apt
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586/ /.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586/apt && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586/apt; rm -rf "/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480352390.01-116502531862586/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"cache_update_time": 0, "cache_updated": 
false, "changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": 
{"allow_unauthenticated": false, "autoremove": false, "cache_valid_time": 
null, "deb": null, "default_release": null, "dpkg_options": "force-
confdef,force-confold", "force": false, "install_recommends": null, "name": 
"rabbitmq-server", "only_upgrade": false, "package": ["rabbitmq-server"], 
"purge": false, "state": "present", "update_cache": false, "upgrade": null}, 
"module_name": "apt"}, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--
force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"     install 
'rabbitmq-server'' failed: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open 
(11: Resource temporarily unavailable)\nE: Unable to lock the administration 
directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?\n", "stderr": "E:     Could 
not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily 
unavailable)\nE: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), 
is another process using it?\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: The issue is most probably related to permissions for "install packages (Ubuntu default repo is used)" task. Can you post your Ansible playbook with this task (`/etc/ansible/roles/rabbitmq/tasks/main.yml`)? Please include your full UserData script as well.

Comment: Unattended upgrades locking the file might be causing this behaviour also. This discussion might be helpful: https://github.com/chef/bento/issues/609

Comment: @MichalGasek I'll post it in a second, but tried something just now and it worked. at the beginning of the user-data I put a `sleep 5m` and it worked so now I'm not sure it's an issue with the user-data or the ansible playbook

Comment: See comment above, it could be Ubuntu's unattended upgrades locking the file.

Comment: Look at this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/953779/programmatically-disable-apt-unattended-upgrades/1196788. It helped me with the same Ansible provision issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same lock issue. I found that ubuntu was installing some packages on first boot which cloud-init did not wait for.

I use the following script to check that the lock file is available for at least 15 seconds prior to trying to install anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

i="0"
while [ $i -lt 15 ] 
do 
if [ $(fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock) ]; then 
  i="0" 
fi 
sleep 1 
i=$[$i+1] 
done
```

The reason I prefer this vs `sleep 5m` because in an autoscale group the instance may be removed before it's even provisioned.